# Segmentation Fault in the program

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to implement a Breadth First Search algorithm for my bomberman type game, there is wall represented by 1 and floor represented by 0. I wanted the function FindDepth to give me the shortest distance from Position A to Position B considering that we cannot overlap the walls. The problem is I am getting segmentation fault in the below program.

```
int FindDepth(int grid[5][5], Position A, Position B)
{
    if ((A.x == B.x) && (A.y == B.y)) return 0;

    int dist[] = {0,0,0,0};
    if(A.x - 1 > -1)
    if(grid[A.y][A.x - 1] == FLOOR) {
        dist[0] = FindDepth(grid, {A.x-1,A.y}, B);
    }

    if(A.x + 1 < 6)
    if(grid[A.y][A.x + 1] == FLOOR) {
        dist[1] = FindDepth(grid, {A.x+1,A.y}, B);
    }

    if(A.y - 1 > -1)
    if(grid[A.y - 1][A.x] == FLOOR) {
        dist[2] = FindDepth(grid, {A.x,A.y - 1}, B);
    }

    if(A.y + 1 < 6)
    if(grid[A.y + 1][A.x] == FLOOR) {
        dist[3] = FindDepth(grid, {A.x,A.y + 1}, B);
    }
    int largest = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(dist[i] > largest) {
            largest = dist[i];
        }
    }   
    return largest;
}
```

This was the full code.

Comment: `if(...)if(...)` can be changed to `if (... && ...)`

Comment: That is not the full code of your program. That is one function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be with this line:

```
if(A.x + 1 < 6)
```

You're checking if A.x+1<6. What if it is 5? grid is an Array of 5 elements which means its indexes are 0 to 4. If A.x+1 is five you're stepping outside the allocated memory for the array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

`A.x + 1 < 6` should be `A.x + 1 < 5`. Likewise for `A.y + 1`.